# If my motherboard has HDMI, will the picture be amazing on my HDTV?

Tags: motherboard, hdmi, hdtv

I have a NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT Card installed.

Comment: Amazing is quite subjective. Please be more specific: browsing the web and watching dvds in 1080p is different then playing crysis at 80 fps in 1080p.

Comment: Also some people here remember when 320x240 was amazing and considered what would now be called High Definition. Please quantify "amazing".

Comment: I only play Age of Empires 3 and watch movies on my pc. i just know that with S-video connection, it's not that great and seems to be offset. Amazing as in, will it look High-Def.

Comment: The NTSC standard has been 525 lines (480 visible, hence 480i) since 1941.  Before then TV was not something experienced by the general populace.  So at no point would it have been likely that 240 lines be considered high definition by anyone at any point in time.

Comment: @ultrasawblade for TV, sure, but not in computer terminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a separate graphics card installed your onboard graphics will be disabled, thus the HDMI port on your motherboard will have absolutely no effect on your picture quality.  If you do not have a graphics card installed you can use the HDMI port on your motherboard.  The picture probably will not be better or worse than using an HDMI port on a high powered graphics card if you are just watching a blu-ray, but if you are playing a game where frames must be rendered then you will notice a big difference between your onboard HDMI port and a high power graphics card (the high powered graphics card being better).